# redirect_to custom http header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, redirect

On my current project, custom http header variable need to be set while redirecting for http basic auth.
Can I instruct redirect_to for custom headers ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rails allows you to add custom headers while redirecting. It is discussed in [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#setting-custom-headers).

> **10.2.1 Setting Custom Headers**
>
> If you want to set custom headers for a response then `response.headers`
>   is the place to do it. The `headers` attribute is a hash which maps
>   header names to their values, and Rails will set some of them
>   automatically. If you want to add or change a header, just assign it
>   to `response.headers`

So your action code would end up being something like this:

```
def some_action
  # do_some_work

  response.headers["your-key"] = "some value"
  redirect_to url
end
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. Maybe it's for api calls only ?

Answer (score 0):

The `request` object's `headers` method can be used to set custom HTTP headers within a controller:

```
request.headers['foo'] = 'bar'
```

Comment: How do you access the request object for a `redirect_to` call?

Comment: That's a request object that represent the request that triggered that action. You probably meant setting `headers` on `response` object. I added a sample code for people who would end up here from google.